# How to send quoted argument to call-process

Tags: command-line-arguments, call-process

I want to use the imagemagick `convert` command to draw on a image file. I have the image data as raw-text in a buffer and now I would like to run `convert - -draw 'rectangle 0,0,100,100' -` on it (the dashes tell convert to use stdin for input and print the data to stdout). If I leave out the `-draw 'rectangle 0,0,100,100'` then I can just use `(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "convert" t t nil "-" "-")` to pass the buffer contents as stdin to the convert program and insert the from `convert` returned image data in the buffer (this does not do anything but it works, e.g. I could replace the last `-` with a filename to write the resulting image data to a file). However now I want to add the `-draw 'rectangle 0,0,100,100'` as an extra argument to `call-process-region` but I really can not find (out) how to do this properly. For example I tried `(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "convert" t t nil "-" "-draw" "'rectangle 0,0,50,50'" "-")` but then I get message `convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition` rectangle 0,0,50,50' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4473.`

I tried to run it as a shell-command (i.e. using `/bin/bash -c`)? But then I don't know how to pass the buffer contents as input.

So I would like to know how to properly pass the single-quotes string `'rectangle 0,0,100,100'` to the command.

(FYI I would like to extend djvu.el to show annotations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to run `convert - -draw 'rectangle 0,0,100,100' -`

Note that you're quoting for the shell there, so that it will not break that argument into two, on account of the space.

> For example I tried `(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "convert" t t nil "-" "-draw" "'rectangle 0,0,50,50'" "-")`

Note that you've included the quotes which are for the shell in a call which is not being processed by a shell, which means that the `convert` process is *receiving* an argument containing those `'` surrounding characters.

That is like running this shell command:

```sh
convert - -draw "'rectangle 0,0,100,100'" -
```

Try:

```el
(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "convert" t t nil
                     "-" "-draw" "rectangle 0,0,50,50" "-")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and nice explanation. It took me a long way to get to this point (trying many things before) and because I really spent too much time already I thought I should just ask here. Then, just after I posted this question I found the function `call-shell-region` which worked for me also. But anyway, your answer helps me to understand why things work how they work, which is very important to me. Great!